# How can I compare a decimal with a hardcoded value?

Tags: c#

Never needed to do this before till now.

trying to make sure the chargeAmount (which is type decimal) does not go below 1 cent:

```
 if (chargeAmount < 0.01)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("chargeAmount");
```

I tried 0.01D but obviously I am not sure how you format this.

Comment: I've edited your title because it didn't represent your question at all.

Answer (score 12):

You mean you want it to be a decimal literal rather than double?

```
if (chargeAmount < 0.01m)
```

Comment: ah crap.  I had tried 0.0M not m (now is time for me to be shamed)

Comment: Hmm, M should work too. Maybe you introduced a typo while you tried that one (nothing worse than those typos that hit on the one attempt that was actually correct).

Answer (score 3):

A [decimal literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) does not use `D` (that's for [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx)) - it uses `M` (for Money):

```
if (chargeAmount < 0.01M)
  throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("chargeAmount");
```

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - not so. From the MSDN page: `If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as decimal, use the suffix m or M`